# Any way to test OAuth integration to google without having to have a port forwarding rule in my router back to my dev PC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

Any way to test OAuth integration to google without having to have a port forwarding rule in my router back to my development Mac?

Background:

- Developing Ruby on Rails web app that will request data from Google Calendar API via OAuth
- Using Rails "OAuth Plugin" for this purpose
- Developing on MacBook which is running my dev environment
- Google needs (as part of OAuth) to make a callback back to my local dev environment

Can't seem to think of a way to test with Google without having to set a Port forwarding rule in my site's router back to my Macbook?

Comment: Actually I think I've misunderstood the protocol.  Google would just issue a redirect response to the call my browser initiated correct?  So this redirect should be able to occur fine and no firewall rule should be required hey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This threw me for a loop too. I actually went through the work of setting it up on a public IP even though I didn't have to in the end.

But yes, your comment is correct. The callback URL is passed on to Google during the redirect then after you've been authenticated with Google, Google will redirect you back to the callback URL providing an authorization code as a parameter.

The only server to server communication that happens is exchanging the authorization code for access and refresh tokens. This typically happens on the callback page. But since it's initiated by your server and not Google, no special open ports are required.